# AS3 - Pass Array from Custom Class To Main.as

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I'm trying to get my array from a custom class so I can use on my main.as file.

Here is what I'm working with.

Main.as:

```
function searchPrize(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var searched_number:Pcnsearch = new Pcnsearch();
    searched_number.searchNum(pcn.text,'fueltest',this.stage);

    // trying to get the array "CReturn from custom class to trace out
    var number_arr:Array = new Array(searched_number.returnSearch());
    trace(number_arr.fName);
}
```

Custom Class: (snippet)

```
public var cReturn:Array = new Array();

public function loader_completed(e:Event)
{
    var person:URLVariables = new URLVariables(e.target.data);
    this.cReturn.pcn = person.one;
    this.cReturn.fName = person.five;
    this.cReturn.lName = person.six;
}


public function returnSearch()
{
    return cReturn;
}
```

what am I doing wrong that is causing me to not return the array into my main.as file?

any help would be great,
Thanks,

Comment: Does it cause an error ? What does it do as a result, what does it print if no error occurs ?

Comment: It causes no errors. It appears that cReturn is returning "null" to my main.as.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cReturn is not being populated before it is being returned.

The steps it takes are:

1. public function searchNum (searches database for requested info)
2. public function returnSearch (returns database results in an array named cReturn)
3. public function loader_complete (loads the database information into the cReturn array)

What I want it to do is:

1. public function searchNum (searches database for requested info)
   **2. public function loader_complete (loads the database information into the cReturn array)
2. public function returnSearch (returns database results in an array named cReturn)**

I will have to use a dispatchEvent inside my loader_complete method (Pcnsearch.as class) with an eventListener inside my main.as script.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you assign a new Array() on number_arr with the array from the class as a parameter. This means that it will return an array with your array inside of it. So you're accessing it wrong.

Any parameters passed to `new Array()` will be elements in the newly created array. What you can do is instead just use `number_arr:Array = searched_number.returnSeach()`

Other than that everything else looks fine and you should have no problem accessing the array returned by your class.

Comment: thanks for helping but still not working. It appears my cReturn array is not collecting the data from the URLVariables. Could this snippet be incorrect?                                                                                                                           `public function loader_completed(e:Event) {
   var person:URLVariables = new URLVariables(e.target.data);
    cReturn.pcn = person.one;
    cReturn.fName = person.five;
    cReturn.lName = person.six;
   }`